# R: Spline Across/Horizontally/Across a Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, interpolation, spline

I have a matrix that is similar to this:

```
    1    2   3    4    5
a  1.4  NA  2.3  0.2  NA
b  NA   3.2 1.2   NA  NA
c  3.5  NA   NA   NA  NA
d  2.1  1.9  NA   NA  NA
```

I need to interpolate the NA's in my matrix.  I was able to do it when I specify which row as in:

```
fmm = spline(x = 1:5, y = RatioNA[1,1:5], xout = 1:5, method = "fmm")
```

but I could not do it for the entire table all at once.

Plus, instead of doing it for each row, it does it for each column.  That is, instead of interpolating in terms of (1.4, NA, 2.3, 0.2, NA), it uses (1.4, NA, 3.5, 2.1).  I need the former.

How do I get spline to do it per row instead of columns without specifying which row?

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  I couldn't figure out how to input a matrix into the editor so that it would look right.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `na.spline` from `zoo` package that use `splinefun` behind the scene. It can interpolate for a matrix or more precisely for a multivariate time series having a `coredate` your matrix. 
But, You should first create multivariate time series with some dummy dates.

```
library(zoo)
mm <- read.table(text='    1    2   3    4    5
a  1.4  NA  2.3  0.2  NA
b  NA   3.2 1.2   NA  NA
c  3.5  NA   NA   NA  NA
d  2.1  1.9  NA   NA  NA',header=TRUE)


## na.spline interpolate by column so you should transpose
d0 <- as.Date("2000-01-01")
vv = na.spline(zoo(t(mm),d0+seq_len(ncol(mm))), na.rm = FALSE)
## you transpose again to get you matrix
t(coredata(vv))

#    X1  X2  X3   X4   X5
# a 1.4 2.7 2.3  0.2 -3.6
# b 5.2 3.2 1.2 -0.8 -2.8
# c 3.5 3.5 3.5  3.5  3.5
# d 2.1 1.9 1.7  1.5  1.3
```

Comment: I don't understand the difference between spline and na.spline.

Comment: it is kind of rapper: `na.spline` uses `spline`  function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function apply to execute a specified function for each row or column of a matrix

Sample Data

```
*txt="    1    2   3    4    5
a  1.4  NA  2.3  0.2  NA
b  NA   3.2 1.2   NA  NA
c  3.5  NA   NA   NA  NA
d  2.1  1.9  NA   NA  NA"
df=read.table(text=txt,header=T)*
```

Sample calculation

```
fmm = spline(x = 1:5, y = df[1,1:5], xout = 1:5, method = "fmm")
```

Function to calculate for each row

```
myFun<-function(yrow){
  fmm = spline(x = 1:5, y = yrow, xout = 1:5, method = "fmm")
  return(fmm$y)
}
```

Evaluate each row of the matrix.  Note, the transpose is needed since the output of "apply" is column vector.

```
df_interp <- t(apply(df, 1, myFun))
```

Resulting output

```
df_interp
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
a  1.4  2.7  2.3  0.2 -3.6
b  5.2  3.2  1.2 -0.8 -2.8
c  3.5  3.5  3.5  3.5  3.5
d  2.1  1.9  1.7  1.5  1.3
```

Comment: You are sending that to the scan function for which `read.table` is a wrapper. You are actually getting numeric values. If you had offered the output of `dput` on you matrix that complexity could have been obviated.

Comment: Reading of text is a standard approach used in the answer in order to replicate the stated problem.  In practice, the matrix can be created in a number of ways, such as reading directly from a file, as numbers.